# List View Action not visible to Community Users

Tags: visual-workflow, customer-community, list-view, quickaction, lightninglistview

**Problem 1:** I have created a new custom Lightning Action which will run a flow. I have edited the relevant object's List View search layout so that the new Action is selected to display in list views. In the internal system, I can see the new list view action, but when I log in as a Community User, I cannot see it.

Why is this? Are List View Actions only available to internal users?

**Problem 2:** As a work around I tried to create a list view button (not an action), and THAT seems to be visible to a community user. However, I am having trouble initiating a screen flow from the list view button -- when I click the button, nothing happens, even though the URL is set to my flow's URL.

Ideally, I'd like to solve Problem 1 first. But if I cannot, then I would like to solve Problem 2.

Answer (score 0):

> Flows in Lightning communities are supported only through the
>   Lightning Flow component.

The easiest way to distribute a flow externally is with the Flow component in Community Builder. Add the Flow component to a page in your Lightning community.

[Embed a Flow in a Community](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_external_community.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that I can embed a flow in a community, but that doesn't always provide a great User Experience -- it sits on the page taking up valuable real estate regardless of whether its needed. I need to run the flow only when the button is clicked from a list view (or any other non-object-specific method).

Comment: @JustinF Did you try wrapping your flow with lighting component? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_cmp.htm

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I'd like to do this declaratively. I'm sure there are lots of ways to accomplish this, I'm just truly shocked that a Community User can't seem to access List View Actions. That's standard functionality, and I can't see any documentation which says that this is the case.

Comment: @JustinF here my point is looks like it only supports **Lightning Flow component** which my guess is using it in a lightning component. Also try using the flow component in app buider to be able to debug that case is true!